# SVM in OpenCV: how to handle unbalance data?

Tags: opencv, svm

For example I have classification problem with 2 classes, but data is skewed(data samples of different classes are in proportion 1:10)

How I can handle unbalance data using SVM?

I found no parameter for weights of different classes ([OpenCV seems have no parameters for this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html)?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has `class_weights` parameter in [`CvSVMParams::CvSVMParams`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvmparams-cvsvmparams).

> class_weights – Optional weights in the C_SVC problem , assigned to
>   particular classes. They are multiplied by C so the parameter C of
>   class #i becomes class_weights_i * C. Thus these weights affect the
>   misclassification penalty for different classes. The larger weight,
>   the larger penalty on misclassification of data from the corresponding
>   class.